# How to write to csv with multiple for in statements

Tags: python

I have a Python 3.7.3 script that reads an XML, parses what I need and is supposed to export the results to CSV. I had to go deeper in the XML tree using a for in loop for one of the fields, which throws off how the other for in statements append to csv.

When running the below, my output file does not list the different V-ID's (refer to the third for child in root... statement), however all the other fields are correct. The V-ID's display correctly when i remove the last for in statement and move the firstFile.write statement 2 tabs to the left, but then I don't have the status, so I know the problem is in the last statement. BTW, if I move the firstFile.write statement all the way to the left, it only returns one row in the csv, but there should be 5.

Is there a way to create a list from the output and then combine them all, or perhaps move the firstFile.write statement two tabs to the left and append the last for in statement to a specific column (essentially breaking up the firstFile.write statement)? Or do you have any other suggestions?
[image: CSV Example]

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
firstFile = open("myfile.csv", "a")
firstFile.write("V-ID,")
firstFile.write("HostName,")
firstFile.write("Status,")
firstFile.write("Comments,")
firstFile.write("Finding Details,")
firstFile.write("STIG Name,")

basePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xmlFile = os.path.join(basePath, "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\XMLtest.xml")
tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}title'):
    d = child.text    

for child in root:
    for children in child.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}target'):
        b = children.text

for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}Group'):
    x = (str(child.attrib))
    x = (x.split('_')[6])
    a = x[:-2]

for child in root:
    for children in child:
        for childrens in children.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}result'):
            x = childrens.text
            if ('pass' in x):
                c = 'Completed'
            else:
                c = 'Ongoing'
            firstFile.write("\n" + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + ',' + ',' + d)
firstFile.close()
```

Comment: Could you please attach your XMLtest.xml file?

Comment: Also it would be nice if you post expected CSV file to better understand your problem

Comment: it kindove sucks but I can't post the XML, it's proprietary of my employer. I will update my main post with the CSV format though.

Comment: It would be surely useful if you post source XML, we need to understand structure, so you can delete all the records except one or two and replace the data with some placeholders

Comment: By now I can say that you iterate through records in wrong way. You iterate through first field (title), then second field (target) and from each column you save only last value. What you need to do is to iterate through records (not separate fields) and then get the data from each record and write to file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write CSV into the next column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446175/how-to-write-csv-into-the-next-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, took about a week to figure this out. I the output to CSV, then read it back into a list for each column, parsed the spaces and wrote it out again. Below is how I did it.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
firstFile = open("myfile.csv", "a")
path = 'C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\xccdf\\'
for fileName in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile1:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile1, delimiter=',')
        # do your stuff
        tree = ET.parse(fileName)
        root = tree.getroot()
        # Stig Title
        for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}title'):
            d = child.text    
        # hostName
        for child in root:
            for children in child.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}target'):
                b = children.text
        # V-ID    
        for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}Group'):
            x = (str(child.attrib))
            x = (x.split('_')[6])
            a = x[:-2]
            firstFile.write(a + '\n')
        # Status
        for child in root:
            for children in child:
                for childrens in children.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}result'):
                    x = childrens.text
                    firstFile.write(',' + b + ',' + x + ',' + ',' + ',' + d + '\n')

with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    vIDs = []
    hostNames = []
    status = []
    stigTitles = []
    for line in csvReader:
        vID = line[0]
        vIDs.append(vID)
        try:
            hostName = line[1]
            hostNames.append(hostName)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            state = line[2]
            status.append(state)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            stigTitle = line[5]
            stigTitles.append(stigTitle)
        except:
            pass

    with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile1.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvFile1:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile1, delimiter=',')
        vIDMod = list(filter(None, vIDs))
        hostNameMod = list(filter(None, hostNames))
        statusMod = list(filter(None, status))
        stigTitlesMod = list(filter(None, stigTitles))
        csvWriter.writerows(zip(vIDMod, hostNameMod, statusMod, stigTitlesMod))
        firstFile.close()
```