# How to write CSV into the next column

Tags: python, csv, elementtree

I have output that I can write into a CSV. However, because of how i setup my XML to text, the output iterates itself incorrectly. I've tried a lot to fix my XML output, but I don't see any way to fix it.

I've tried a lot, including modifying my XML statements to trying to write to CSV in different ways, but I can't seem to get the rows to match up the way I need them to be, because of the the for in statements that have different depths.

I don't really care how it's done, so long as it matches up, because the data is ultimately fed into my SQL database.

Below is my code,

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
firstFile = open("myfile.csv", "a")
firstFile.write("V-ID,")
firstFile.write("HostName,")
firstFile.write("Status,")
firstFile.write("Comments,")
firstFile.write("Finding Details,")
firstFile.write("STIG Name,")

basePath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
xmlFile = os.path.join(basePath, "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\XMLtest.xml")
tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}title'):
    d = child.text    
for child in root:
    for children in child.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}target'):
        b = children.text
for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}Group'):
    x = (str(child.attrib))
    x = (x.split('_')[6])
    a = x[:-2]
    firstFile.write("\n" + a + ',')
for child in root:
    for children in child:
        for childrens in children.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}result'):
            x = childrens.text
            if ('pass' in x):
                c = 'Completed'
            else:
                c = 'Ongoing'
            firstFile.write('\t' + '\n' + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + ',' + ',' + d)
firstFile.close()
```

below is my CSV current output,
[image]

below is the output I need,

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add an example of `XMLtest.xml`? Also, is there any reason you can't use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the XML is really large and proprietary. I can use CSV, which I'm looking into now. I was thinking about turning each for in statement output to a list, and then building the columns in CSV. But i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Based on the namespaces you use in your code it appears that you're using the XCCDF spec. From what I can see the schema(s) for that spec are publicly available. You should be able to create a small enough test file that matches the structure of your actual file, but has dummy data instead of your company's data. What I would do is build up a dictionary for each row and use [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write those rows to the output. This could be done with multiple for loops, but there might be an easier way. Hard to tell without sample XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me. I basically left it as is, put it into a CSV, then read the CSV, stored the columns as a list, removed blank spaces and exported it back out.

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
firstFile = open("myfile.csv", "a")
path = 'C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\xccdf\\'
for fileName in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')):
    with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile1.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile1:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile1, delimiter=',')
        # do your stuff
        tree = ET.parse(fileName)
        root = tree.getroot()
        # Stig Title
        for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}title'):
            d = child.text    
        # hostName
        for child in root:
            for children in child.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}target'):
                b = children.text
        # V-ID    
        for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}Group'):
            x = (str(child.attrib))
            x = (x.split('_')[6])
            a = x[:-2]
            firstFile.write(a + '\n')
        # Status
        for child in root:
            for children in child:
                for childrens in children.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}result'):
                    x = childrens.text
                    firstFile.write(',' + b + ',' + x + ',' + ',' + ',' + d + '\n')

with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    vIDs = []
    hostNames = []
    status = []
    stigTitles = []
    for line in csvReader:
        vID = line[0]
        vIDs.append(vID)
        try:
            hostName = line[1]
            hostNames.append(hostName)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            state = line[2]
            status.append(state)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            stigTitle = line[5]
            stigTitles.append(stigTitle)
        except:
            pass

    with open('C:\\Users\\JT\\Desktop\\Scripts\\Python\\myfile1.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvFile1:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile1, delimiter=',')
        vIDMod = list(filter(None, vIDs))
        hostNameMod = list(filter(None, hostNames))
        statusMod = list(filter(None, status))
        stigTitlesMod = list(filter(None, stigTitles))
        csvWriter.writerows(zip(vIDMod, hostNameMod, statusMod, stigTitlesMod))
        firstFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this
   x = (x.split('_')[0])

Answer (score 0):

Think of what your CSV output looks like, then think of what it SHOULD look like.

Your CSV is generated by these two loops:

```
for child in root.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}Group'):
    x = (str(child.attrib))
    x = (x.split('_')[6])
    a = x[:-2]
    firstFile.write("\n" + a + ',')
for child in root:
    for children in child:
        for childrens in children.findall('{http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2}result'):
            x = childrens.text
            if ('pass' in x):
                c = 'Completed'
            else:
                c = 'Ongoing'
            firstFile.write('\t' + '\n' + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + ',' + ',' + d)
```

That means that anything you add to your CSV file in the second loop will be written AFTER what was added in the first loop.

I can think of two ideas to solve this from the top of my head:

1. Somehow fuse the loops into one, thus generating each row in one loop iteration. I don't know if that works with your parameters, though.
2. Don't add to the end of the CSV file, but add to the row you want to add by specifically telling the "write" function where to write.

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Python at all, this is just the logical source of the problem and two solutions that should work in theory. I do not know if either of them is practicable.